# Table transform

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table:

[image]

Each ID is double on the 'ans' and 'num' lines

I need to convert to this. Here 'ans' and 'num' are the field names and the values below.

[image]

Maybe you've already had a case like this and have a solution or an idea in which direction to go.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Queries do not get along well with mixed data.**
So we use alternative methods.

Please use the following formula and adjust ranges to your needs

```
={QUERY(FILTER(G2:J32,I2:I32="num"),"select Col1, Col2, Col4",0), 
  QUERY(FILTER(G2:J32,I2:I32="ans"),"select Col4",0)}
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)

Comment: Cool thanks. This is a good solution, but this sample is small. In the actual data, these fields "num" and "ans" have different names and there are more. Is there a more flexible solution?

Comment: *"Cool thanks. This is a good solution"* It solves the issue you posted for. So you could accept the answer. *"this sample is small. In the actual data, these fields "num" and "ans" have different names and there are more."* If that is the case, solutions can be very different. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped. You may even have to post a new question.